# How to detect whether GPU is AMD or NVIDIA from inside HIP code

Tags: c++, hip

I'm currently writing a HIP equivalent to NVIDIA's [deviceQuery](https://github.com/NVIDIA/cuda-samples/tree/master/Samples/1_Utilities/deviceQuery) sample code. I want [my code](https://github.com/wyphan/testcodes/tree/master/cpp-hip-device-info) to work on both AMD and NVIDIA hardware.
Now, `hipDeviceProp_t` isn't exactly the same as `cudaDeviceProp_t`, because the former has both new and missing fields in the struct compared to the latter.
Currently the code I wrote works on AMD GPUs only and segfaults when I try it on an NVIDIA GPU, which I believe is due to accessing fields that are nonexistent in `cudaDeviceProp_t`. It is also still missing a critical part to detect the exact GPU model within the same `gfx???` GCN architecture code.

How do I figure out whether the detected GPU is AMD or NVIDIA?

Edit: for comparison, SYCL has `sycl::info::device::vendor` that provides this information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using HIP you known at compile time if you are compiling for AMD or Nvidia GPUs. There is [no support for both AMD and Nvidia GPU code in the same translation unit](https://rocmdocs.amd.com/en/latest/Programming_Guides/HIP-FAQ.html#can-a-hip-binary-run-on-both-amd-and-nvidia-platforms).

Thus you could try relying on the following pre-processor definitions:

```c
#if defined(__HIP_PLATFORM_AMD__)
    // AMD GPU code should take this code path
#elif defined(__HIP_PLATFORM_NVIDIA__)
    // Nvidia takes this code path.
#else
    #error "Unknown platform"
#endif
```

Comment: Finally, something that doesn't rely on anything else outside HIP! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Also, I heard fat binary support will be coming in LLVM 15, so once ROCm/HIP picks it up, then it will be possible to have both AMD and NVIDIA GPU binaries in the same executable.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the vendor ID with [`IDXGIAdapter::VendorId`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/dxgi/ns-dxgi-dxgi_adapter_desc). If you need to get a vendor's ID, there are websites like [PCI Lookup](https://www.pcilookup.com/).

You will need a Direct3D and DXGI device.

```cpp
#define VENDOR_NVIDIA 0x10DE

extern IDXGIAdapter* pDXGIAdapter;

std::string GetGPUVendor()
{
    DXGI_ADAPTER_DESC Description;
    if (SUCCEEDED(pDXGIAdapter->GetDesc(&Description)))
    {
        switch (Description.VendorId)
        {
            case VENDOR_NVIDIA:
                return "NVIDIA";
            // ...
            default:
                return "Unknown";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return "Failed";
    }
}
```

Comment: Welp, unfortunately Direct3D is out of the question here, since I'm developing for Linux.

Comment: @wyphan If you can use OpenGL, you can use glGetString(GL_VENDOR). It should return "NVIDIA Corporation" for NVIDIA, and "ATI Technologies Inc." for most AMD cards.

Comment: I can use OpenGL, thanks!